# JSON extraction and casting to MySQL types

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Is there a way to convert a JSON field into its corresponding "native" MySQL type, without explicitly casting it?

Suppose I have a table with these fields:

```
# table `test`
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
json JSON NOT NULL
```

I insert some JSON, like this:

```
{field1: "abc", field2: 100}
{field1: "def", field2: 20}
```

I'd like to sort by `field2`, which is numeric, but without having to cast it.  It seems like this should be possible, given that all `field2` values are JSON numbers.  Is this possible?

```
select * from test order by CAST(json->>'$.field2' as unsigned) desc
                            ^
                            └ Is there an alternative to doing this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tricky way(*multiplication by one*) in order to cast as number implicitly as an alternative case :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM test 
 ORDER BY json->>'$.field2'*1 DESC
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=27282439150ec1a1874656cf9b11c8ed)</kbd>

Comment: This seems to be technically correct, and is certainly nice to know, but my question was more along the lines of casting the JSON to whichever datatype it most resembles in MySQL, without having to know it ahead of time.  I will edit my question to be more clear.

Comment: On second thought, you answered the question perfectly and I think what I'm asking for is impossible anyway, as `->>` returns a `utf8mb4` string, which must be cast if further type-based manipulation is desired.